# How to write SQL query for this Given Scenerio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Attributes of `Empl_Table`: `Emp#` (P.K), `Emp_Name`, `Salary`, `Department#` (f.k)

I have to find the result:

- First column : `Department#`
- Second column: Sum Of salaries of the employees of each department where name starts with 'A'
- Third column: Total salary of all the employee of that department

Result should be like this

```
Department#   NameContains'A'   TotalSalary 
-------------------------------------------- 
    10            2450             8750 
    20            1110            10875
    30            7900             9400
```

Answer (score 3):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
select et.department,
       sum(case where Name like 'A%' then salary end) as A_salary,
       sum(salary) as total_salary
from empl_table et
group by et.department;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Department#,
       Sum(CASE
             WHEN ename LIKE 'A%' THEN salary
           END) Emp_A_Salary,
       Sum(salary) Total_salary
FROM   Empl_Table
GROUP  BY department#
```

Comment: department# probably should be [escaped].